# Unable to update android studio lint settings

Tags: android-studio, apk, android-gradle-plugin, lint, release-mode

I am using android studio 1.1.0. I want to disable specific lint checks like 'Incomplete Translation'. So, I went to File -> Settings... -> Inspections -> Android Lint and unchecked 'Incomplete Translation' item, then pressed Apply & OK buttons. Now, generating signed apk still throws lint errors related to missing translations.

Further on, I disabled entire Android Lint item to see if generation of signed apk skips lint error checking or not. Result is I still got same lint errors for missing translations whereas I was expecting no lint error checking as per updated settings. Is this the bug from android studio or am I doing something wrong here?

Note that I don't want to disable lint error checking entirely, which I can do easily by adding following lines under build.gradle:

```
lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
}
```

**I just want to turn off few lint checks from settings dialog.**

Answer (score 0):

As per the official doc http://tools.android.com/tips/lint/suppressing-lint-warnings

"***To suppress an error, open the issue in the editor and run the quickfix/intentions action (Ctrl/Cmd F1) and select Suppress which will use annotations, attributes or comments to disable the issue.***"

OR You can specify translatable tag for your resource to configure this.

Either one by one

```
<string name="hello" translatable="false">hello</string>
```

OR entire resource

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  tools:ignore="MissingTranslation" >

  <!-- Other strings no need of translatable attribute -->

</resources>
```

***To know more about lint settings configurations***

***Read this*** http://tools.android.com/tips/lint/suppressing-lint-warnings

Comment: Sure, I know about these solutions, but settings dialog is preferable for me as far as it's working, because my question is mainly for 'lint settings not updating in android studio'. I would like to turn off specific lint issue ids directly. Missing translation is just one such example.